# How to do SQL "NOT LIKE" in Slick

Tags: scala, slick

I'm quite new to both Scala and Slick. A "LIKE" query was easy to make

```
query.filter(_.name like "%kjelle%")
```

but I'm not successful trying to do a "NOT LIKE" query. Couldn't find a notlike operator so my first thought was to try

```
query.filter(_.name !like "%kjelle%")
```

or

```
query.filter(!(_.name like "%kjelle%"))
```

but no success.

How can I do it in Slick?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try to use `filterNot`:

```
query.filterNot(_.name like "%kjelle%")
```

Comment: That solved my problem. So easy to miss the obvious when you are new to something.